# Hive insert into table from select statement with different schemas

Tags: hive, hiveql

For two tables in Hive:

```
Schema of Table A:
id  name  age

Schema of Table B:
name

# The type of "name" in Table A and B are both string
```

I want to select all rows from `Table B` and then append them to `Table A`, leaving the columns `id` and `age` null.

The following statement would not work since the number of columns are not identical

```
insert into Table_A
select * from Table_B
;
```

Is there any viable methods to append the data?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
insert into table Table_A select null,name,null from Table_B;
```